# Quick SQL question

Tags: string, postgresql

Working on postgres SQL.

I have a table with a column that contains values of the following format:

Set1/Set2/Set3/...

Seti can be a set of values for each i. They are delimited by '/'.

I would like to show distinct entries of the form set1/set2 and that is - I would like to trim or truncate the rest of the string in those entries.
That is, I want all distinct options for:

Set1/Set2

A regular expression would work great: I want a substring of the pattern: .*/.*/

to be displayed without the rest of it.

I got as far as:

> select distinct column_name from table_name

but I have no idea how to make the trimming itself.

Tried looking in w3schools and other sites as well as searching SQL trim / SQL truncate in google but didn't find what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest you change the title to something meaningful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they really are that regular you could use [`substring`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-SQL); for example:

```
=> select substring('Set1/Set2/Set3/' from 1 for 9);
 substring 
-----------
 Set1/Set2
(1 row)
```

There is also a version of `substring` that understands POSIX regular expressions if you need a little more flexibility.

The PostgreSQL online documentation is quite good BTW:

> http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html

and it even has a usable index and sensible navigation.

---

If you want to use `.*/.*` then you'd want something like `substring(s from '[^/]+/[^/]+')`, for example:

```
=> select substring('where/is/pancakes/house?' from '[^/]+/[^/]+');
 substring 
-----------
 where/is
(1 row)
```

Comment: Nope, it is not that regular. Set1 can be a set of values as well as set 2. They are delimited by '/'.
A regular expression would work great: I want a substring of the pattern: .*/.*/

Comment: @Lost_DM: You probably want `[^/]+/[^/]+` as in my update then.

Comment: Your update, after my answer, is exactly what my answer said. Sigh.

Answer (score 2):

mu is too short's answer is fine if the the lengths of the strings between the forward slashes is always consistent. Otherwise you'll want to use a regex with the substring function.

For example:

```
=> select substring('Set1/Set2/Set3/' from '^[^/]+/[^/]+');
 substring 
-----------
 Set1/Set2
(1 row)

=> select substring('Set123/Set24/Set3/' from '^[^/]+/[^/]+');
  substring   
--------------
 Set123/Set24
(1 row)
```

So your query on the table would become:

```
select distinct substring(column_name from '^[^/]+/[^/]+') from table_name;
```

The relevant docs are http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-string.html
and http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-matching.html.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you store multiple values in a single record? The preferred solution would be multiple values in multiple records, your problem would not exist anymore.

Another option would be the usage of an array of values, using the [TEXT[] array-datatype](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/arrays.html) instead of TEXT. You can index an array field using the [GIN-index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-types.html).

SUBSTRING() (like mu_is_too_short showed you) can solve the current problem, using an array and the [array functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-array.html) is another option:

> SELECT    array_to_string(
>       (string_to_array('Set1/Set2/Set3/', '/'))[1:2], '/'    );

This makes it rather flexible, there is no need for a fixed length of the values. The separator in the array functions will do the job. The [1:2] will pick the first 2 slices of the array, using [1:3] would pick slices 1 to 3. This makes it easy to change.